# self modifying rules in an expert system

Tags: expert-system, self-modifying

is there any way to make the rules on an Expert System be modified by the system itself so tha t it can learn from its experiences? 
-suggestions are always welcome.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is "yes" there are ways to do that.  For example, the "if" part of the rule can be dependent on a numerical value (e.g., a prior probability).  When the rule is triggered, the "then" part of the rule can update the prior, which changes the rule.  If you are asking about structural changes to a rule, that is also possible (you could make a rule dependent on condition assertions that may be created, modified, or removed) but the extent to which that is possible will depend on the particular expert system shell you are using.